# Issue with nested parameterized routes and deep-links (e.g. bookmarks)

Tags: aurelia

I've created a [full repro of this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/LarsKemmann/aurelia-NestedRoutesIssue) with instructions to reproduce.

Essentially, when creating a **nested** parameterized route, a deep-link still resolves to the right place *but* dynamically-created elements don't get initialized with the right link. Only by navigating between routes do dynamically-created links (`route-href` bindings) get initialized properly.

**UPDATE: Here's another attempt to explain the issue:**

When deep-linking to a nested page that has `<a route-href` bindings, the links seem to be initialized without awareness of the parent context. E.g., where an item link located on the view for `http://localhost:9000/#/primary2/secondary2/` *should* have an `href` of `http://localhost:9000/#/primary2/secondary2/item/1` it only gets the last part: `http://localhost:9000/#/item/1`.

### App.ts

```
configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router){
  config.title = 'Aurelia Nested Routes Issue';
  config.map([
    { route: '', redirect: 'primary1' },
    { route: 'primary1',  moduleId: 'primary1', name:'primary1', nav: true, title: "Primary 1" },
    { route: 'primary2',  moduleId: 'primary2', name:'primary2', nav: true, title: "Primary 2" }
  ]);
  this.router = router;
}
```

### Primary2.ts

```
configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router){
  config.map([
    { route: '', redirect: 'secondary1' },
    { route: 'secondary1',  moduleId: 'secondary1', name:'secondary1', nav: true, title: "Secondary 1" },
    { route: 'secondary2',  moduleId: 'secondary2', name:'secondary2', nav: true, title: "Secondary 2" }
  ]);

  this.router = router;
}
```

### Secondary2.ts

```
configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router){
    config.map([
        { route: '',          moduleId: 'no-item',   title: 'Select an item'},
        { route: 'item/:id',  moduleId: 'item-detail', name:'item' }
    ]);
    this.router = router;
}
```

### secondary2.html

```
<ul>
  <li repeat.for="item of items">
    <a class="${item == $parent.currentItem ? 'active' : ''}" route-href="route: item; params.bind: {id:item.id}">
      ${item.description}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<hr>
<router-view></router-view>
```

Answer (score 2):

One small adjustment would make the original version work.

Populate `this.items` on `attached()` event instead of `constructor()`, because  `configureRouter()` will be called after `constructor()` but before `attached()`.

This way the router will have a chance to become aware of additional child routes before `repeat.for` generates the list items.

**secondary2.ts**

```
constructor() {
}

attached() {
  this.items.push(new Item(1, "Item 1"));
  this.items.push(new Item(2, "Item 2"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still learning the event pipeline. I will give that a try.

Comment: This works really well for custom elements that need to bind to the navigation items on a child router as well.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround (recommended by Aurelia community member [@TylerJPresley](http://tylerjpresley.com/)) is to use a global routes table and manually-defined links. This still allows the use of `route-href` on the dynamic item links; it appears to be the nested parent routes that throw it off.

Code example is in the [workaround-globalRoutes](https://github.com/LarsKemmann/aurelia-NestedRoutesIssue/tree/workaround-globalRoutes) branch in the repository on GitHub.